# if down required in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking

I have a server running Ubuntu 17.04 with three IPv4 addresses and a /64 IPv6 block, and the `/etc/network/interfaces` that was pre-installed by my provider only has `up ip address add .../32 dev eth0` for the two additional IPv4 addresses, but no `down ip address del .../32 dev eth0` like I usually see in configs. Is the `down` part not needed at all?

Comment: Are you getting any error upon shutting down the interface? Does the current setup has any problems? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's just that I wanted to know if `down ip address del...` is required per IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All addresses on the interface will be removed when you run `ifdown` on the interface.  It is not necessary to down IP addresses added to an interface before downing the interface itself.

The old mechanism using separate names for alternate IP addresses could leave alternate IP addresses configured in some cases.  The new approach of adding additional IP addresses to the same interface is much cleaner.